# How to use lapply to save the new output as a seperate list/unlisted objects? lapply, list, select

Tags: r, list, function, select, lapply

I am trying to select specific rows of cleaned dataframes. I can do this simply by using select for one dataframe then repeating the code for x amount but this is inefficient and untidy. I think lapply is appropriate here. I have therefore made a list of the x dataframes and the column names I would like to select are in select_vector.

My approach currently that seems the best is using lapply on the list, with select as the function then the select_vector to select only the columns with names that are in the vector.

How would it be possible to make it so the new frames in the list are saved? x <- x is not overwriting the original frame and hence to me seems redundant in the code.

I have tried a few things but would like to use lapply so it can be done as tidily as possible and I can learn more about the function.

Example code is:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

select_vector <- c("Country", "Year", "Description", "Value")

lapply(df_list, function(x) {x <- x %>% select(select_vector)} )
```

The output is the frames with the selected columns, unfortunately I cant get them to save as a new list or as frames not in a list object.

Thanks.

Comment: lapply(df_list, function(x) {x <- x %>% select(select_vector)} ) %>% do.call(rbind,.)?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

You need to assign the output of `lapply()` to a variable.

```r
df_list_filtered <-
  lapply(df_list, function(x)
    x %>% select(all_of(select_vector)))

df_list_filtered
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    Country  Year Description Value
#>    <chr>   <int> <chr>       <chr>
#>  1 A        2002 A           a    
#>  2 B        2003 B           b    
#>  3 C        2004 C           c    
#>  4 D        2005 D           d    
#>  5 E        2006 E           e    
#>  6 F        2007 F           f    
#>  7 G        2008 G           g    
#>  8 H        2009 H           h    
#>  9 I        2010 I           i    
#> 10 J        2011 J           j    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    Country  Year Description Value
#>    <chr>   <int> <chr>       <chr>
#>  1 A        2002 A           a    
#>  2 B        2003 B           b    
#>  3 C        2004 C           c    
#>  4 D        2005 D           d    
#>  5 E        2006 E           e    
#>  6 F        2007 F           f    
#>  7 G        2008 G           g    
#>  8 H        2009 H           h    
#>  9 I        2010 I           i    
#> 10 J        2011 J           j    
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    Country  Year Description Value
#>    <chr>   <int> <chr>       <chr>
#>  1 A        2002 A           a    
#>  2 B        2003 B           b    
#>  3 C        2004 C           c    
#>  4 D        2005 D           d    
#>  5 E        2006 E           e    
#>  6 F        2007 F           f    
#>  7 G        2008 G           g    
#>  8 H        2009 H           h    
#>  9 I        2010 I           i    
#> 10 J        2011 J           j
```

You can simplify the code a bit

```r
df_list_filtered <-
  lapply(df_list, select, all_of(select_vector))
```

If the dataframes have the same columns it is more performant and it might also
make things easier to bind them into on single dataframe before subsetting
the columns.

```r
df_list |>
  bind_rows(.id = "origin") |>
  select(origin, all_of(select_vector))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 5
#>    origin Country  Year Description Value
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr>       <chr>
#>  1 1      A        2002 A           a    
#>  2 1      B        2003 B           b    
#>  3 1      C        2004 C           c    
#>  4 1      D        2005 D           d    
#>  5 1      E        2006 E           e    
#>  6 1      F        2007 F           f    
#>  7 1      G        2008 G           g    
#>  8 1      H        2009 H           h    
#>  9 1      I        2010 I           i    
#> 10 1      J        2011 J           j    
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I have one thing that I'm not sure if it can be avoided when using bind_rows. When I try to convert the frame to wide so that the column names include description (to make it easier to plot and removing the need to have the description column), the resultant frame is keeping the id column and therefore has a lot of unnecessary rows repeating years because of the origin column.  Would there be any way to remove there being an origin column? Can I just not use .id =?

Comment: You can leave out the `.id` argument if you don't need it: `... |> bind_rows()`.